# Need help in building a regular expression

Tags: jmeter

Need help on building a regular expression to extract the value "2:_id93" and the uid. Here there are multiple sets of data with different status. How ever, i would like to search for the values corresponding to "In Update"

In Update

Comment: It would appear some data is missing from your post?

Comment: In Update</td>
<td class="policyCol10"><a href="#" onclick="showProcessing();;return oamSubmitForm('searchResults','searchResults:policytableId:2:_id93',null,[['uid','xsdfsdfa-yyy-asdf-123443-sdfde1234']]);"

Comment: Edit the original post by pressing the edit link.  Comments do not allow for proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below regular expression?

In Update(.*?)policytableId:(.*?)',null,\[\['uid','(.*?)'

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns the above data
2. Configure it like:

   - Name of created variable: anything meaningful, i.e. `id`
   - Regular Expression: `In Update.*searchResults:policytableId:(.+?)'`
   - Template: `$1$`

     [image]
3. That's it, you should be able to access the extracted value as `${id}` where required.

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl5 Regex Cheat Sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)